# Is converting an int into a generic possible?

Tags: java

Assuming T is generic is there anyway to get something like this to work?

```
public T cast(int n){
 T toReturn = (T) n;
 return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: No it is not. Please post your functional requirement to get more accurate help.

Comment: No, its not possible. You can not convert your int to any class type.

Comment: The answer is no, but what would this even mean? What would you expect the behavior to be for, say, `HttpURLConnection connection = cast(123)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do: `T toReturn = (T)(Integer)n;`, which would compile, and would even run so long as `T` was always one of the three types `Integer`, or its supertype `Number`, or its supertype `Object`, but it probably wouldn't be very useful.

A typecast of an object will always give you the same reference, so it can only let you access types that the object actually has. You can't create an `Integer` and then cast it to (for example) a `Double`, because an `Integer` is not a `Double`, and a typecast of objects won't create a new object. If you want to create an instance of some other type from an int, you have to call a method able to specifically create instances of that type.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a primitive such as an `int` to an object.  The best you can do to is to box the `int` into an `Integer`, for instance:

```
public Integer cast(int n){
    Integer toReturn = Integer.valueOf(n);
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: If this is Java 5 or higher, you can just say `return n;`.

Comment: That's true @gparyani.  I didn't want to mention it because the automated boxing can be confusing to inexperienced programmers.

Comment: Learning autoboxing turn inexperienced programmers into experienced programmers.

Comment: @Luiggi So instead of working hard for 20 years, I should have just learnt autoboxing?  Damn!

Comment: That's part of 20 years of experience.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest thing I can think of to what you want.  You might have an interface something like

```
public interface ValueSettable{
    void setValue(int value);
}
```

and you could have a bunch of classes that implement this, like this one.

```
public class FunkyValue implements ValueSettable{
    private int value;
    public void setValue(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then, you could write something like this.

```
public static <T implements ValueSettable> T cast(int value, Class<T> toInstantiate){
    T toReturn = toInstantiate.newInstance();
    toReturn.setValue(value);   
    return toReturn;
}
```

and when it comes to use it -

```
FunkyValue funky = cast(47, FunkyValue.class);
```